# Spring data jpa repository integration test using JNDI datasource

Tags: spring, jpa, junit, jndi

We are using JNDI datasource for spring data JPA repository datasource.
While writing integration tests, tried to create the JNDI datasource as below.
But still the

```
SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
DriverAdapterCPDS cpds = new DriverAdapterCPDS();
cpds.setDriver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
cpds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true");
cpds.setUser("");
cpds.setPassword("");

SharedPoolDataSource dataSource = new SharedPoolDataSource();
dataSource.setConnectionPoolDataSource(cpds);
dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
dataSource.setMaxWait(50);
builder.bind("jdbc/testDB", dataSource);
builder.activate();
```

Getting the below exception when running the maven JUnit Tests

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
```

Comment: Could you please post the other configuration files? You have forgotten something in your "jpaMappingContext" bean definition.

Comment: Does exception shows also in main application , or only in Tests?

Comment: Exception is only in the tests. Main application is running fine.